# How to add a Video/Live splash screen in eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse

I already know how to add a picture from drawable to eclipse as a splash screen. 
But I would like to know if someone could give me some advice on how to add a video instead of the image. Kind of like EA with their games and apps!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could display a browser on the splashscreen and embed the video in the displayed website. Take a look at the Browser-Template on the Splash-Tab of the Eclipse Product-Editor.